# Magento - add customer company name to new order email subject

Tags: magento

I want to add the customer's company name to new order email subject in Magento 1.4.1.1

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{{var billing.company}} should do the trick

Comment: Where have I to add this exactly ? Thanks.

Comment: You add it to the transactional email in your admin UI. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else.  Magento processes the transactional email templates through a filter.  The filter looks for {{ ... }} style tags to process and replace. {{var ...}} is one of the tags that gets processed.  The new order email template is passed several variables, one of which is the billing address.  The billing address has a member variable for company. Knowing all of that, you create the tag shown above: {{var billing.comany}}